# A good tutorial for using AccountManager in Android?

Tags: java, android, oauth, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

Does anyone know of any good tutorials for using AccountManager in android, basically what I'm trying to do is request a OAuth2 token to use with a google api, any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: best source my friend : https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html

Comment: another best tutorial: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

Comment: Hello there, I was looking for a tutorial on account manager, and today I found this repository: https://github.com/SamuGG/android-account-manager-example

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

Doesn't get much more official than this